# Google drive from different account

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive

I have google drive installed on my on my everyday account. Now I would like to use google drive with another account.

When I sign in with  another account I have message:

```
The account you entered does not match. Please sign in again with your evrydayaccount@gmail.com account to proceed.
```

How I can temporary use another_account's google drive in my PC
 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this would obliterate any security Drive would have.

But you can 'share' the files from one account to another, and the other account can have as much access as you need.

From Google's [site](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en):

- While you have a file open: Click Share in the top-right corner.
- While you have a folder open: Click the share icon in the top-right Share.
- From your file list in Drive: Select the name of a file or folder and click the share icon at the top

Rereading your question, you could also signout of one Drive and signin to the other? I don't think having two Drives integrated into Windows at once is possible though.

Comment: **Actually....You can...**  You just can't do it with the default Google Drive client.

Comment: @Ramhound never knew that, what is this 'non-default' client?

Comment: There are several.  The official client lets you sync a single Google Drive account at a time, there are other clients, that let you sync multiple at one time.